# Undefined object error in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a newbie to d3; I've encountered this very basic debugging error. And I already spent quite a bit of time on it but can't figure out the solution.

I suspect that since it gives me`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.map')`. Within `x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.DATE; })));` maybe `function(d {return d.DATE;})` wasn't correct.

```
d3.csv("student_debt.csv", type, function(error, data) {
x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.DATE; })));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.FGCCSAQ027S; }))]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());
```

I've already checked the file name etc. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: put a `console.log(data)` at the second line and tell us what you get. Also, please share the `type` function.

Comment: Well, S.O. is a pretty active community therefore, when asking a question, it's a good idea sticking around for some minutes, to answer the comments... Anyway, edit your question when you have a chance, so people can better help you.

Comment: Yay, I figured it out!! I actually have the wrong type question. Thanks a lot for the advice! ;)